# When using L'Hopital's rule and differentiating the top and bottom with respect to h, can I conclude this?

Tags: calculus

I am answering a question that involves an integrable function $f$ on an open interval centered at a point $a$. I have represented this interval as $(a-h, a+h)$. I gotten to the point where I have

$\frac{F(a+h) - F(a-h)}{2h}$

where $F$ represents the antiderivative of $f$ and I am using it to represent the integral of $f$ from $a-h$ to $a+h$. I need to take the limit of this as $h$ approaches $0$ so then I have

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0}$$\frac{F(a+h) - F(a-h)}{2h}$

I am trying to show that as $h$ goes to $0$, this limit will equal $f(a)$.  I used L'hopital's rule since the top and bottom of the fraction go to zero and get

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0}$$\frac{F'(a+h) - F'(a-h)}{2}$

=$\frac{2F'(a)}{2} = F'(a) = f(a)$

I am just confused as to whether or not I can actually do this since when using l'hopital's rule, I believe I am differentiating the top and bottom with respect to h. So I am wondering if I can actually then make this conclusion that I am trying to make. I apologize if this is a dumb question, I'm fairly new to these types of problems

Comment: Your calculation is correct, since in general $\frac{d}{dh}F(a+h)=\frac{d}{da}F(a+h)$ and $\frac{d}{dh}F(a-h)=-\frac{d}{da}F(a-h)$.

Comment: @ Kavi and Kagartsch: If $F'=f$ is only integrable then it is not guaranteed that $\lim_{h \to 0}F'(a+h)=F'(a)=\lim_{h \to 0}F'(a-h).$

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am also given that f is continuous as well on the same interval. Does this mean that my calculation is correct? I didn't write out the whole question here as to save space but I realize that that was probably a mistake

Comment: Yes, if  f  is continuous, then your calculations are correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Caution !

1. If you use L'Hospital you get $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F'(a+h) + F'(a-h)}{2}$ and not $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F'(a+h) - F'(a-h)}{2}$ , since you differentiate with respect to $h$.
2. We only have $ \lim_{h \to 0}F'(a+h)=F'(a)$ and $ \lim_{h \to 0}F'(a-h)=F'(a)$ if $F'=f$ is continuous in $a$. This is not guaranteed, since $f$ is only integrable !

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that I am given that f is integrable and continuous

Comment: If f is continuous,  then f is integrable.